# media is canceled as status only after packaging in electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron, p5.js

I have an electron app, everything works perfectly, like its meant to, until I package it.

The app is an interactive film, it loads the scenes after the user makes a decision, everything works with npm start, however when I package, it the beginning works and so does the option after that, however the third option you have when you click on the button (Which should call the function which loads in the video) doesn't work. In the debugger it says the status is canceled, not sure why...

This is the code for that function that isn't working (All other scene functions up to that point work) I am using p5.js as the frontend library.

```
function scene2opt2() {
    scene2option2 = createVideo('assets/scene2option2.mp4');
    scene2option2.size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
    scene2option2.play();
    console.log(scene2option2);

    function scene2opt2end() {
        scene2opt2ended = true;
        cursor()
    }
    scene2option2.onended(scene2opt2end);
}
```

For the whole code go to my github: https://github.com/Reddamhouse/thief/blob/app/sketch.js 
(Line 173)

Comment: I think it must be something wrong with my videos headers, because no matter where I put that scene it doesn't work. Maybe the file is too big? It's my biggest file at 170mb

Comment: Check that the videos are in the `.asar` file generated by the packager.

Comment: Instead of posting your whole code, can you please include a [mcve] in your post?

Comment: did you tried to add a module to open your console when it's packaged?

Comment: I didn't really figure it out, however I got a new .mp4 and it works fine. Maybe the file was corrupted or something.